# Banach space convergence

Tags: banach-spaces

Having $X$ , a Banach space. Show that $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ implies that for all functions $f$ contained in $X^\ast$ (dual), $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: Sequential definition of continuity makes this entirely trivial. Note that even linearity of $f$ need not be explicitly used.

Comment: See Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X^\ast$ denotes the vector space of *continuous* linear functionals

$f:X \to \Bbb F, \tag 1$

where $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb F = \Bbb C$ is the base field, then every $f \in X^\ast$ is bounded, *viz*,

$\exists 0 < C_f \in \Bbb R, \; \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \le C_f \vert x - y \vert, \; \forall x, y \in X; \tag 2$

then if

$x_n \to x \; \text{as} \; n \to \infty, \tag 3$

given $0 < \epsilon \in \Bbb R$ we have, for $n$ sufficiently large,

$\vert x_n - x \vert < \epsilon; \tag 4$

thus, for such $n$,

$\vert f(x_n) - f(x) \vert \le C_f \vert x_n - x \vert < C_f \epsilon; \tag 5$

taking $\epsilon$ small enough ensures $C_f \epsilon$ is itself arbitrarily small, whence we see that (5), by definition, implies that

$f(x_n) \to f(x) \; \text{as} \; n \to \infty. \tag 6$

Comment: For a finite dimension of X , the reciprocal would be true right? Because of isomorphism

Comment: @mimi: in finite dimensions, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Look how you define the norm of $f$ for $f \in V^*$: $$\|f\|_* = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{\lvert f(z) \rvert}{\|z\|}.$$ In particular, for any fixed $x \in X$, we see $$\|f\|_* \ge \frac{\lvert f(x) \rvert}{\|x\|}  \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, \lvert f(x) \rvert \le \|f\|_* \|x\|.$$ Now suppose that $x_n \to x$ in $X$; that is, suppose that $\|x_n - x\| \to 0$. What can you say about $\lvert f(x_n) - f(x)\rvert?$

Comment: I don't understand why the proof has to be so complicated. Isn't this simply continuity of $f$? By definition  every element of the dual space is a continuous function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  what is it you find so complicated about this proof?  It seems the author has covered the essentials in a failry minimalist manner.  Cheers!

Comment: I suppose it's fine to just assert that $f$ is continuous. I'm just giving a quantitative measure of continuity here. I don't see that this is particularly complicated; the whole argument concludes in roughly 6 lines.

Comment: I can't see any proof which is *less* complicated!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  I would be happy to read a less complicated proof if you would care to produce one!

Comment: @RobertLewis Please read my comment just below the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  I did.  Now show us *how*, show us the *details*, if you would!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  it strikes me your comment is a *comment* on a proof, but not quite a proof in and of itself.

Comment: It seems like you've just skirted around the question by invoking a different definition; meaning that this depends on how you define the dual space: $X^*$ could be defined as the set of all linear maps $f : X \to \mathbb F$ such that $$\|f\|_* = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{\lvert f(z) \rvert}{\|z\|} < \infty.$$ In that case, you would have to prove that any element of the dual space is indeed (sequentially) continuous in order to invoke your comment.

Comment: @RobertLewis If $f$ is a continuous function on a topological space and $x_n \to x$ then   $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. I don't understand what proof you are asking for. Am i really missing something here?

Comment: @RobertLewis The usual definition of the dual of a normed linear space is it is the set of all continuous linear functionals.  I haven\t see any book where the definition of the dual space is given in terms of the operator norm.